# Time Complexity of nested loops including if statement

Tags: time-complexity, nested-loops

I'm unsure of the general time complexity of the following code.

```
Sum = 0
for i = 1 to N
    if i > 10
        for j = 1 to i do
            Sum = Sum + 1
```

Assuming i and j are incremented by 1.
I know that the first loop is O(n) but the second loop is only going to run when N > 10. Would the general time complexity then be O(n^2)? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's n^2.  10 is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the definition of Big O Notation.

`________________________________________________________________`

Let *f*: ℜ → ℜ and *g*: ℜ → ℜ.

Then, *f*(*x*) = *O*(*g*(*x*))
⇔ 
∃ *k* ∈ ℜ ∋ ∃ *M* > 0 ∈ ℜ ∋ ∀ *x* ≥ *k*, |*f*(*x*)| ≤ *M* ⋅ |*g*(*x*)|

`________________________________________________________________`

Which can be read less formally as:

`________________________________________________________________`

Let *f* and *g* be functions defined on a subset of the real numbers.

Then, *f* is *O* of *g* if, for big enough *x*'s (this is what the *k* is for in the formal definition) there is a constant *M* (from the real numbers, of course) such that *M* times *g*(*x*) will always be greater than or equal to (really, you can just increase *M* and it will always be greater, but I regress) *f*(*x*).

`________________________________________________________________`

(You may note that if a function is *O*(*n*), then it is also *O*(*n*²) and O(*e*^*n*), but of course we are usually interested in the "smallest" function *g* such that it is *O*(*g*). In fact, when someone says *f* is *O* of *g* then they almost always mean that *g* is the smallest such function.)

Let's translate this to your problem. Let *f*(*N*) be the amount of time your process takes to complete as a function of *N*. Now, pretend that addition takes one unit of time to complete (and checking the if statement and incrementing the for-loop take no time), then

*f*(1) = 0

*f*(2) = 0

...

*f*(10) = 0

*f*(11) = 11

*f*(12) = 23

*f*(13) = 36

*f*(14) = 50

We want to find a function *g*(*N*) such that *for big enough* values of *N*, *f*(*N*) ≤ M ⋅*g*(*N*). We can satisfy this by *g*(*N*) = *N*² and *M* can just be 1 (maybe it could be smaller, but we don't really care). In this case, *big enough* means greater than 10 (of course, *f* is still less than *M*⋅*g* for *N* <11).

**tl;dr:** Yes, the general time complexity is *O*(*n*²) because Big O assumes that your N is going to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your code is

```
Sum = 0
for i = 1 to N
   for j = 1 to i do
       Sum = Sum + 1
```

There are `N^2` sum operations in total. Your code with `if i > 10` does `10^2` sum operations less. As a result, for enough big `N` we have

```
N^2 - 10^2
```

operations. That is

```
O(N^2) - O(1) = O(N^2)
```